# How to execute a query with Amazon Athena without exhausted resources?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to do this query to obtain some data. The size of the files that I have on s3 in s3://my_datalake/my_table/year=2018/month=9/day=7/ is 1.1 TB and I have 10014 snappy.parquet Objects.

```
SELECT  array_join(array_agg(distinct endpoint),',') as endpoints_all, count(endpoint) as count_endpoints 
    FROM my_datalake.my_table  
    WHERE year=2018 and month=09 and day=07 
    and ts between timestamp '2018-09-07 00:00:00' and timestamp '2018-09-07 23:59:59'
    and status = '2'
    GROUP BY domain, size, device_id, ip
```

But I got that error:

> Query exhausted resources at this scale factor

```
(Run time: 6 minutes 41 seconds, Data scanned: 153.87GB)
```

I have partitions YEAR, MONTH, DAY and HOUR. How can I do this query? Can I do it with Amazon Athena or I need to use another tool?

The schema of my table is:

```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `ssp_request_prueba`(
  `version` string, 
  `adunit` string, 
  `adunit_original` string, 
  `brand` string, 
  `country` string, 
  `device_connection_type` string, 
  `device_density` string, 
  `device_height` string, 
  `device_id` string, 
  `device_type` string, 
  `device_width` string, 
  `domain` string, 
  `endpoint` string, 
  `endpoint_version` string, 
  `external_dfp_id` string, 
  `id_req` string, 
  `ip` string, 
  `lang` string, 
  `lat` string, 
  `lon` string, 
  `model` string, 
  `ncc` string, 
  `noc` string, 
  `non` string, 
  `os` string, 
  `osv` string, 
  `scc` string, 
  `sim_operator_code` string, 
  `size` string, 
  `soc` string, 
  `son` string, 
  `source` string, 
  `ts` timestamp, 
  `user_agent` string, 
  `status` string, 
  `delivery_network` string, 
  `delivery_time` string, 
  `delivery_status` string, 
  `delivery_network_key` string, 
  `delivery_price` string, 
  `device_id_original` string, 
  `tracking_limited` string, 
  `from_cache` string, 
  `request_price` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` int, 
  `month` int, 
  `day` int, 
  `hour` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://my_datalake/my_table'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1538747353')
```

Comment: Could you send more information about you data source ? Is it on S3 or db ? Example of data. What format of data do you use ?

Comment: It is on s3. The fields domain, size, device_id, ip, and endpoint are strings. Example: domain= stackoverlow.com. Size=6x6, device_id= a15848sdsd, ip= 127.0.0.7, endpoint=VASTSDSDSDS128.

Comment: Could you send table definition by using "SHOW CREATE TABLE my_datalake.my_table; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably related to array_join and array_agg functions. I suppose that in this mentioned case the memory limit of node in Athena service has been exceeded. Probably Athena is not able to manage such amount of data  in combination with these functions.

Comment: I just tried that but I got the same problem: Query exhausted resources at this scale factor (Run time: 6 minutes 57 seconds, Data scanned: 133.91GB)

Comment: what size of the files do you have on s3 for these partitions which you use in the query? I mean in s3://my_datalake/my_table/year=2018/month=9/day=7/

Comment: s3://my_datalake/my_table/year=2018/month=09/day=07/

10014 Objects - 1.1 TB

Comment: Yes, part-00000-361a1c7d-c6c4-4e30-bbae-4c00dad5ec59.c000.snappy.parquet

Comment: Does the query work? What is the result ?                                         SELECT   count(endpoint) as count_endpoints 
    FROM my_datalake.my_table  
    WHERE year=2018 and month=09 and day=07 
    and ts between timestamp '2018-09-07 00:00:00' and timestamp '2018-09-07 23:59:59'
    and status = '2'
    GROUP BY domain, size, device_id, ip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181355/discussion-between-j-b-gorski-and-eric-bellet).

Comment: This query "SELECT count(endpoint) as count_endpoints FROM my_datalake.my_table WHERE year=2018 and month=09 and day=07 and ts between timestamp '2018-09-07 00:00:00' and timestamp '2018-09-07 23:59:59' and status = '2' GROUP BY domain, size, device_id, ip " it finish correctly (Run time: 21 minutes 53 seconds, Data scanned: 365.65GB)

Comment: How many endpoints did you receive ? I suppose that you have too many endpoints in the result of your query and this error is connected to array_join and array_agg functions. I mean that probably these functions are not able to handle such amount of data/ endpoints.

Comment: I tested these functions on 168709 endpoints on my sample data. My query was sucesfully completed but in the result my internet browser has hung up, so I cannot see the result of the query.

Comment: Per row, I can have max 100 endpoints. Do u tested with 1 TB of data or doesn't matter?

Comment: My sample data has not more than 10GB, but maybe in your case you exceeded the memory limit per node in athena service. I tested also a few variants of the query, with array_join(array_agg(distinct endpoint),','), with array_agg(distinct endpoint) and with count(distinct endpoint), all variants scans the same amount of data on s3, so probably it is memory issue.

Comment: Okay, the issue is that I exceeded the memory limit per node in Athena service.

Comment: You can try to transform your data first by using AWS Glue or EMR

Comment: What do you mean? I transform the data with EMR, basically, I have all in Kafka and with Spark, I extract, transform and load the data in a bucket s3. Do you mean after all this process?

Comment: I mean that you can for instance put your query into EMR and generate flat files for later queries in Athena. You have quite large datalake so I suppose that you will have a lot of problems in executing ad-hoc queries on this. I think that you should transform partialy the data and create subset of your data before executing queries in Athena.